# How to grep the intended folder names in a given range?

Tags: regex, grep

I have got a directory of the following sub-directories:

> 01abc 01abb 01abc 01abd ... 01abz

What I want to do is to grep all the folder names except for a `range` of the sub-directories

> 01abw 01abx 01aby 01abz

So I am wondering how can I `grep` the rest of the files?

Comment: What do you mean "grep the folder names"?  You mean you want to do something like `grep -R` within those folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood your question, but it looks quite simple:

```
01ab[a-v]
```

Comment: so the grep command should be something like `grep "01ab[a-v]"` or `grep -v "01ab[w-z]"`, just for reference